# Can I inject php code in the url in part thats displayed on screen?

Tags: php, security, inject, exploit

Hey this is my very simple code:

```
<?php
$test= $_GET['test'];
echo $test;

?>
```

And in the url I wrote this:

```
test.php?test=system('dir')
```

Why does it not execute the command and why is it not displayed?

Comment: You should never allow to execute a script sent from a user.

Comment: Yikes! Do you want someone to be able to hack your server?

Comment: I think you are trying to create ( or to understand ) a PHP Shell. Nobody in the right mind would do something like this. ( no offense )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the command as a string in the URL. Furthermore you're simply "echo-ing" the string to the screen. While an echo could include escaped php code which would be run, you might instead want to evaluate and run the command.

To actually run the command you can use either of the following commands:

- [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)
- [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
- [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Make sure to read the documentation of [safe-mode-exec](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir) as well.
Especially the following bit:

> safe_mode_exec_dir string If PHP is used in safe mode, system() and
>   the other functions executing system programs refuse to start programs
>   that are not in this directory. You have to use / as directory
>   separator on all environments including Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You pass a string via the URL, an echo won't execute a string. You need to write:

```
eval($test)
```

to execute it. So your current code can't execute PHP code, but it could be used to execute JS code. You should filter it.

Checkout the documentation about filters to learn more about filtering: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.filter.php. You could also use such a library: https://github.com/ircmaxell/filterus. If you are working with some framework, checkout the integrated filtering functions / methods.